# C Socket requests getting buffered

Tags: c, sockets

I have a simple server-client model. In which Server sends some encrypted message to client. The client then uses the first few characters of the message to decide the processing. The problem is that these messages are getting buffered one after another hence I am loosing the all messages buffered after the first one. Is there a simple way to prevent buffering or tell the send function to flush.

Comment: You can try to minimize client-side buffering using TCP by enabling *TCP no-delay*, which disables [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm). You can't prevent the client not reading your whole message all at once, however; depending on how you're doing the I/O, you could block until you read the entire message -- or, if non-blocking, just implement a state machine. PS you can stop losing data by not overwriting unread data in your input buffer with each `recv` (assuming Berkeley or POSIX sockets) ;-)

Comment: thanks. I tried disabling Nagle's algo. but somehow the problem remained.

Comment: How do you decide how many bytes to `recv` in your client? What do you mean exactly by "loosing all messages"?

Comment: What is happening is unclear. You mean that Server sends three messages, yet Client only reads one? This would look like improper communications between client and server or a data handling error, not a buffering problem at all.

Comment: Sorry everyone for not being more precise. The thing is that server used to send messages to client in format Op1___ and Op2_____ etc. The thing was that sometimes the send function and the recv function buffers them so that my assumption on the client side that the first few characters are differentiating the type of message was not working. Anyway as in my other comment I figured out how to solve it. @MarkTolonen I will try to keep that in mind. I rarely use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client has to determine how many bytes should be read for it to process. The server will send one message after another, but the streaming socket allows the bytes to flow as if it is one long message. Your messages need some way to allow the client to know when one ends and the next one begins.

The easiest way to do that in a streaming socket is to prepend the message with the length of the message. So the client first reads the length, then the client reads that many bytes.

```
int send_message (int sock, const void *message, uint32_t len) {
    int r;
    uint32_t mlen = htonl(len);
    r = send(sock, &mlen, 4, 0);
    /* ...error checking... */
    r = send(sock, message, len, 0);
    /* ...error checking... */
    return ok ? len : error;
}

int recv_message (int sock, void *buf, uint32_t size) {
    int r;
    uint32_t mlen;
    r = recv(sock, &mlen, 4, 0);
    /* ...error checking... */
    mlen = ntohl(len);
    /* ...check buf is large enough... */
    r = recv(sock, buf, mlen, 0);
    /* ...error checking... */
    return ok ? mlen : error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I guess the easiest way is to add a token character say $ after every server message and tokenize is accordingly on the client side. This maintains efficiency by not disabling nagle's algorithm.